# Connotations of "sack" as a verb

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I was reading the article ["South Africa's President Zuma sacks finance minister"](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-africa-39451040) on BBC. Why was the verb "sack" used instead of "dismissed"? Does it evoke a stronger feeling - positive or negative one?

Comment: It's more colloquial and often more brutal.

Comment: The same as fired in AmE.

Comment: Yep, fired, dismissed, let go, sent walking.  Generally implies a negative context, when the firee has done something to draw the ire of his superiors.

Comment: Headline writers need to optimize for space. So even if the register of the word is slightly off, the shorter word is preferred. The article itself uses longer synonyms like dismissal, resignation etc. Also, 'sacking' has become acceptable in the register anyway from frequent use. To me, it does have a more brutal feel than 'dismissed', like the 'sack of Rome' sounds more final than 'a foreign army entered the city of Rome without permission'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verb 'to sack' is a shortening of the phrase 'give the sack to' meaning 'dismiss from employment'. Apparently it is thought to be derived from the idea of a tradesman taking his bag of tools away with him when he leaves a job. See http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/151100.html